# If several different Vertex Buffers are bound to different input slots of the D3D11 pipeline, which one is used by the Draw() call?

Tags: buffer, draw, direct3d, vertex, slot

Two somewhat related questions, really.

FIRST: If I have different - and differently sized - Vertex Buffers **A and B** bound to the pipeline input **slots 0 and 1**, then which one of them will be used in the

```
ImmediateContext->Draw(VertexCount, StartVertexLocation)
```

function call?

SECOND: If no buffer is bound to slot 0, while the Vertex Buffer B is still bound to slot 1, then should the Draw(...) call use B ?

In my very possibly erroneous understanding, the Draw(N, ...) call should draw N vertices from each of the bound buffers, however many...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Multistream rendering* does not allow you to have different vertex counts in each VB. If you are using Index Buffers, the same index is used for all bound vertex buffers.

Essentially the *multistream rendering* is just a way to pick up different parts of a single vertex from multiple buffers at rendering time, not another indexing method. All the logic for which slot to pull from is controlled by the Input Layout's `D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC.InputSlot`. For example, you can have position in slot 0, texture coordinates in slot 1, normals in slot 2, or some other combination.

> You may find [this](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Multistream-rendering-and-instancing) *DirectX Tool Kit* tutorial helpful